# configuration["string"] doesn't actually get the key from user secrets

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I have a function that I am trying to use IConfiguration and then the correct syntax to pull locally from user secrets. I haven't touched this project in 8 months, but was tasked with going through all the dependencies and update them to the latest but still stay on .NET 6.

I went from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Usersecrets 5.0 -> 6.0.1. I am guessing there was some change implemented but clearly I am an idiot and can't find release notes or changes between the versions

This function has been plugging along working just fine but now that I am revisiting it in development, for some reason I can't pull any info out of my user secrets. My laptop was wiped in that time, therefore I did have to create new user secrets and I pulled this repo down from devops. I don't have any app.settings or local.json files due to that reason as well.

Things I have tried: making sure all of the correct packages are installed, making sure the user secrets folder is in the correct location on the file system, reinstall / installing Extensions.UserSecrets, making sure the ID in csproj matches the ID on the file system, simplifying the JSON so it isn't nested but unfortunately nothing has worked. I have spent hours trying to figure out the solution but keep coming to a dead end.

I have a service that creates IConfiguration in the constructor as follows:

```
public GetGraphClientService(ILogService logService, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.logService = logService;
    this.configuration = configuration;
}
```

In a method down below I attempt to access this via

```
configuration["Foo:Bar"]
```

No matter how I try to access the key, it comes back null. There are no errors or anything to point me in the right direction so I have ran out of ideas on how to solve this.

I feel like I am probably overlooking something simple but can't quite figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

**`Function.cs:`**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

namespace FunctionApp63
{
    public  class Function1
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public Function1(IConfiguration dIConfiguration)
        {
            this._config = dIConfiguration;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public  async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string secret_from_file = _config.GetSection("Foo:Bar").Value;

            string value = secret_from_file;
            Console.WriteLine("The secret Value is :"+value);
            return new OkObjectResult(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**`host.json:`**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**`csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
      <UserSecretsId>f40355f5-dc79-4991-b208-c02a6ec06be1</UserSecretsId>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`Secrets.json:`**

```
{
  "Foo:Bar":"Rithwik is Secret"
}
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]